# Maximum number of negative coefficients $p(x)^2$ can have

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, contest-math

Here is the problem $2$ of the 83rd William Lowell Putnam Mathematical Competition.

> Let $n$ be an integer with $n \ge2$. Over all real polynomials
> $p(x)$ of degree $n$, what is the largest possible number of
> negative coefficients of $p(x)^2$?

I attempted to look at the case where $n = 2$ on WA and found that no matter what coefficients of $p(x) = ax^2 +bx+c$ the maximum negative coefficients of $p(x)^2$ is $2$.

I started to think it is the case that the maximum is just equal to n because we can simply alternate the signs to guarantee this result. But when I tried $n=3$ I found for example that

> $(x^3 -x^2 -x +1)^2 = x^6 -2x^5 -x^4 +4x^3 -x^2-2x+1$
> has 4 negative coefficients and it seems that if we have negative coefficients for $x^2$ and $x$ this will be the case.

I'm pretty much stuck here and any help is appreciated. Perhaps combinatoric may help here.

Comment: One way would be to expand $(a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0)^2$. Notice an upper bound is immediately $2n-2$ as the first and last terms will be positive. From there look at the exponents of the coefficients.

Comment: @DavidP I think the upper bound is $2n-1$, since there are $2n+1$ terms in $(a_nx^n + \cdots + a_0)^2$ if we include the constant term.

Comment: **Hint** (does not lead to complete solution): Consider $(Ax^n- x^{n-1}- x^{n-2}-\cdots - x + A)^2$, for $A>0$.

Comment: @DavidP I've tried for smaller cases and showed that for n=3 the maximum is indeed 4. However, when I tried with n-degree p(x) things don't turn out so smoothly. I notice that the coefficients will be repeating in this sort of pattern (at least for the first few terms) :$2a_na_{n-2} + a_{n-1}^2$ for even exponents and $2a_na_{n-3} + 2a_{n-1}a_{n-2}$ for the odd ones. I could keep going but am I heading in the right direction?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Note: I assume that we are restricting ourselves to polynomials with real coefficients.*

We claim that the answer is $2n - 2$, which can be achieved with the polynomial $$p^*(x) = nx^n - x^{n-1} - x^{n-2} - \dots - x + n.$$

In this answer, we always assume $n \geq 2$ as stated in the question.

(Thanks to @MikeEarnest for a hint for the polynomial in his comment.)

---

**Claim 1.** *The polynomial $(p^*(x))^2$ has $2n-2$ negative coefficients.*

*Proof.* Let
$$(p^*(x))^2 = b_{2n}x^{2n} + b_{2n-1}x^{2n-1} + \dots + b_1x + b_0$$
for some coefficients $b_0, b_1, \dots, b_{2n}$. We also write

$$p^*(x) = a_{n}x^{n} + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \dots + a_1x + a_0$$
where $a_i = -1$ if $1 \leq i \leq n-1$, and $a_i = n$ otherwise, as defined in our earlier definition of $p^*(x)$.

- Clearly, $b_0 = a_0^2 = n^2 > 0$ and $b_{2n} = a_n^2 = n^2 > 0$.
- For integer values $i$ from $1$ to $n-1$ (inclusive), we have
  \begin{alignat*}{11}
  b_i &= a_i a_0 &&+ a_{i-1}a_1 &&+ a_{i-2}a_2 &&+ \dots &&+ a_1a_{i-1} &&+ a_0 a_i \\
  &= (-1)(n) &&+ (-1)(-1) &&+ (-1)(-1) &&+ \dots &&+ (-1)(-1) &&+ (n)(-1) \\
  &= (-n) &&+ 1 &&+ 1 &&+ \dots &&+ 1 &&+ (-n).
  \end{alignat*}
  We get $b_i = -2n + (i-1) < 0$, so $b_i$ is negative in this case.
- Similarly, for integer values $i$ from $n+1$ to $2n-1$ (inclusive), we have
  \begin{alignat*}{11}
  b_i &= a_{n}a_{i-n} &&+ a_{n-1}a_{i-n+1} &&+ a_{n-2}a_{i-n+2} &&+ \dots &&+ a_{i-n+1}a_{n-1} &&+ a_{i-n} a_n \\
  &= (n)(-1) &&+ (-1)(-1) &&+ (-1)(-1) &&+ \dots &&+ (-1)(-1) &&+ (-1)(n) \\
  &= (-n) &&+ 1 &&+ 1 &&+ \dots &&+ 1 &&+ (-n).
  \end{alignat*}
  We get $b_i = -2n + (2n-i-1) < 0$, so $b_i$ is also negative in this case.
- Finally, for $b_n$:
  \begin{alignat*}{11}
  b_n &= a_{n}a_{0} &&+ a_{n-1}a_{1} &&+ a_{n-2}a_{2} &&+ \dots &&+ a_{1}a_{n-1} &&+ a_{0} a_n \\
  &= (n)(n) &&+ (-1)(-1) &&+ (-1)(-1) &&+ \dots &&+ (-1)(-1) &&+ (n)(n) \\
  &= n^2 &&+ 1 &&+ 1 &&+ \dots &&+ 1 &&+ n^2.
  \end{alignat*}
  So $b_n = 2n^2 + (n-1)$ and is obviously positive.

Hence, $(p^*(x))^2$ has exactly $2n-2$ negative coefficients. Specifically, all of its coefficients are negative, except the coefficients for $x^{2n}$, $x^n$, and $x^0$. $\blacksquare$

---

We now want to prove some smaller claims to eventually prove that $(p(x))^2$ cannot have $2n-1$ negative coefficients.

**Claim 2.** *Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ whose constant term is $1$, and let $k$ be a positive integer with $k \leq n$. If the coefficients of $x^{1}$, $x^{2}$, $x^{3}$, $\dots$, $x^{k}$ in $(p(x))^2$ are negative, then the coefficients of $x^{1}$, $x^{2}$, $x^{3}$, $\dots$, $x^{k}$ in $p(x)$ must be negative too.*

(Note that the $p(x)$ above cannot be any real polynomial. But we will generalize our result later.)

*Proof.* Let us write
$$p(x) = a_{n}x^{n} + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \dots + a_1x + a_0$$
and
$$(p(x))^2 = b_{2n}x^{2n} + b_{2n-1}x^{2n-1} + \dots + b_1x + b_0$$
for some coefficients $a_0, a_1, \dots, a_n, b_0, b_1, \dots, b_{2n}$, with $a_0 = 1$.

We prove by induction on $k$.

The base case $k = 1$ is straightforward to prove; we know $b_1 = 2a_0a_1 = 2a_1$, so $b_1 < 0$ implies $a_1 < 0$.

For the inductive step, assume that the case holds $k = k'$ for some positive integer $k' < n$. We want to show that the claim also holds when $k = k' + 1$, that is, if $b_1, b_2, \dots, b_{k'+1}$ are all negative, then $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_{k'+1}$ are all negative too.

Indeed, by our induction hypothesis, we know that $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_{k'}$ must be negative because $b_1, b_2, \dots, b_{k'}$ are negative. Furthermore,
\begin{align*}
b_{k'+1} &= a_0 a_{k' + 1} + a_1 a_{k'} + a_2 a_{k' - 1} + \dots + a_{k'} a_1 + a_{k' + 1} a_0 \\
&= (1 \cdot a_{k' + 1}) + a_1 a_{k'} + a_2 a_{k' - 1} + \dots + a_{k'} a_1 + (a_{k' + 1} \cdot 1) \\
&= 2a_{k' + 1} + a_1 a_{k'} + a_2 a_{k' - 1} + \dots + a_{k'} a_1.
\end{align*}
Since $b_{k'+1}$ is negative and $a_1 a_{k'}$, $a_2 a_{k' - 1}$, $\dots$, $a_{k'} a_1$ are all positive (since they are the product of two negative numbers), we know that $a_{k' + 1}$ must be negative.

This completes our induction proof. $\blacksquare$

---

We prove Claim 2 because we want this important corollary.

**Corollary 3.** *Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ whose constant term is $1$. If the coefficients of $x^{1}$, $x^{2}$, $x^{3}$, $\dots$, $x^{n}$ in $(p(x))^2$ are negative, then all of the coefficients of $x^{1}$, $x^{2}$, $x^{3}$, $\dots$, $x^{n}$ in $p(x)$ must be negative too.*

*Proof.* Use Claim 2, with $k = n$. $\blacksquare$

And with the help of this corollary, we can finish our answer.

**Claim 4.** *Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ whose constant term is $1$. Then $(p(x))^2$ cannot have $2n-1$ negative coefficients.*

*Proof.* We prove by contradiction. Again, let us write
$$p(x) = a_{n}x^{n} + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \dots + a_1x + a_0$$
and
$$(p(x))^2 = b_{2n}x^{2n} + b_{2n-1}x^{2n-1} + \dots + b_1x + b_0$$
with $a_0 = 1$.

Suppose that $(p(x))^2$ has $2n - 1$ negative coefficients. Then *all* of its coefficients except $b_0$ and $b_{2n}$ must be negative. After all, it only has $2n + 1$ coefficients, and we know that $b_0 = a_0^2 = 1^2 > 0$ and $b_{2n} = a_n^2 > 0$.

In particular, $b_1$, $b_2$, $\dots$, $b_n$ must be negative. Therefore, we can apply Corollary 3 to $p(x)$ to infer that $a_1$, $a_2$, $\dots$, $a_n$ must be negative too.

However, if $a_{n-1}$ and $a_n$ are negative, then $b_{2n-1} = 2a_{n-1}a_n > 0$. This contradicts the statement from earlier that *all* of the coefficients in $(p(x))^2$ except $b_0$ and $b_{2n}$ are negative. $\blacksquare$

---

We are almost done with our answer. To prove that Claim 4 also holds for all polynomials in general, we can use contradiction again.

Here is an outline for the proof: Assuming such a degree-$n$ polynomial $p(x)$ exists:

- If $p(x)$'s constant term is $1$, then by Claim 4, $(p(x))^2$ cannot have $2n-1$ negative coefficients.
- If $p(x)$'s constant term is not $1$, but nonzero, then divide the polynomial by the constant term to obtain another polynomial $q(x)$. The number of negative coefficients in $(q(x))^2$ must also be $2n-1$. (Why?) But that contradicts Claim 4.
- If $p(x)$'s constant term is $0$, consider the polynomial $q(x) = p(x) / x$. The number of negative coefficients in $(q(x))^2$ must also be $2n-1$. (Why?) However, this would lead to a contradiction; $(q(x))^2$ only has $2n-1$ coefficients, so all the coefficients must be negative, which is impossible.

---

*A final note on a special case.* The proof is not valid when $n = 1$. One reason is in our proof for Claim 4:

> However, if $a_{n-1}$ and $a_n$ are negative, ...

When $n = 1$, this means we assume $a_0$ is negative. But we have assumed earlier that $a_0 = 1$.

In fact, Claim 4 is false if we allow $n = 1$. A counter-example is $(x-1)^2 = x^2 - 2x + 1$ with $1$ negative coefficient. It contradicts Claim 4 which would state that it cannot have more than $2n - 2 = 0$ negative coefficients.

Comment: Really nice answer.